# String.IsNullOrEmpty is not detecting the Escape sequence NULL \0 in C#

Tags: c#, string, null, escaping, isnullorempty

I tried the following if statement but if fails to detect the NULL

```
void Main()
{
    string str = "\0".Trim();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        "Empty".Dump();
    }
    else
    {
        "Non-Empty".Dump();
    }
}
```

Kindly refer the LinqPad snapshot

[image]

I got the output

```
Non-Empty
```

I don't know how its failing. Kindly assist me.

Comment: The output is correct. The string is _not_ empty, it contains a `'\0'`. In C, strings are terminated by a binary zero, in C#, there is no such convention.

Comment: Maybe it is the LinqPad showing it that way? I tried in VS 2013 and the value "\0"

Comment: by replace you can remove all \0 from your string

Comment: Can you elaborate why you expect a non-empty string to be empty?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I goth-roughed the escape characters, in that I noticed `\0` is represented as `null`. I'm a beginner so I tried this `\0` in `string.IsNullorEmpty`, but it fails. That's the reason I posted this question.

Comment: `0` is nowhere representing `null`, where do you get that from?

Comment: `\0` Null - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That is the *name* of the character, not the representation in C# (`null`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string contains one character `\0`.
This character is non-printable, so you don't see it in Watches, but if you add `str.Length` to watches, you will see "1".

So, is your string null? Definitely, no. Is it empty? No, it contains characters.
Hence, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` logically results into `false` and it outputs "Non-Empty".

If for some reason you receive strings containing `\0` characters and want to treat it as an empty string, you can just trim `\0` as well:

```
string str = "\0".Trim(new[] { '\0', ' ', '\t' });
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
    "Empty".Dump();
}
else
{
    "Non-Empty".Dump();
}
```

This will output "Empty".

As suggested by Patrick Hofman, it is better to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` since it is more suitable for this case and can handle a wider range of white-space, non-visible, BOM characters etc..

Comment: Why did you remove the use of `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, which is better suited for this?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I decided to use `IsNullOrEmpty` because it is closer to the OP's code and because `Trim()` guarantees that if string was whitespace-only it would become empty. However, you are right, `IsNullOrWhiteSpaces` is something smarter than just trim whitespaces and tabs, so I mentionted it in comments. Thank you.

Comment: But still, IsNullOrWhiteSpaces does not detect \0 so trim is still required for thatspecific case.